# Excel - Writing to text file with Format(date)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that can create and write text file. Below is the code:

```
Public Sub createFil()


Dim fso As Object
Dim datetext As String

Const FLDR_NAME As String = "C:\testing"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateFolder (FLDR_NAME)

Dim Fileout1 As Object

Set Fileout1 = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\testing\test.txt", True, False)
datetext = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value & "Hello World"
Fileout1.Write datetext
Fileout1.Close

End Sub
```

As you can see, C2 value is "HI" and F2 value is current date which is "=today()".

At the result file, the date format i get is "2/15/2017". but the format that I want is "02/15/17".

I have changed the format at Excel sheet for the F2. Am i missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the date in VBA before outputting it:

```
datetext = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & _ 
    Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & _ 
    "Hello World"
```

Comment: @Om3r that's not a problem, good answers always add value, especially when they provide an alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this after **`Dim Fileout1 As Object`**

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. This is extra info